# MySQL join 2 tables and result should be IN third_table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I got 3 tables: requests, d_requests (delivery requests) and s_requests (send requests).

part of "d_requests" and "s_requests" is always the same (userID, ticket_creation_date and some other data). So it was chunked from these tables and put to "requests" upon each insert to db.

Now I need to do following: JOIN requests and d_requests selecting some data, and then I need to make sure that such selection is IN s_requests' column "send_before"

```
SELECT r.type, r.request_from, r.request_to, d.departure_date
    FROM requests as r
    JOIN d_requests as d ON r.request_id = d.requests_id
    WHERE r.type='d' AND r.request_from='Beijing' 
    AND r.request_to='Tokyo' AND d.departure_date 
          IN (SELECT s.s_before from s_requests s where s.s_before<='user_defined_date')
    ORDER BY d.departure_date
```

I have a result, but it's partial. As I see from the DB, it should give me some several rows of output while it only generates a table with 1 row. Even if I set "user_defined_date" to something like 2025-12-12, output is still 1 row (while all tickets are in 2017 and early 2018).

Comment: If you remove the final condition (d.departure_date in ...) does it then return more records? If so, then at least you know that there's something wrong with that condition. Maybe the d.departure_date doesn't match exactly with the s_before dates in the other table. i.e. if the seconds or milliseconds are different? Isn't it better to just compare the departure date with the user_defined_date?

Comment: @RichS yes, without a subquery, the query is returns more results.

Comment: @RichS Isn't it better to just compare the departure date with the user_defined_date? - that is exactly what I am doing, but to do this, I need to look into 3 tables.

Comment: To ascertain why the records aren't matching, can you run a separate query with just the subquery. The compare the departure_dates with records in the subquery? If they don't match exactly, that will be why the query isn't returning what you're expecting.

Comment: I understand that ultimately I need SELECT from 2 subqueries, being: (1) JOIN between requests and s_requests on ID, (2) JOIN between requests and d_requests on ID, and after 2 subqueries, I would need to compare this all in resulting table and order by departure_date. Problem is: I feel it may be done easier way (either restructure or reformat slightly the schema itself or by alternative structure of request itself, and I would prefer the latest option of these two, but cant do it really =).

Comment: Don't you need **s.requests_id = r.request_id** in the subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need something like this

```
SELECT r.type, r.request_from, r.request_to, d.departure_date
FROM requests as r
INNER JOIN d_requests as d ON r.request_id = d.requests_id
INNER JOIN s_requests as s ON r.request_id = s.requests_id
WHERE r.type='d' AND r.request_from='Beijing' 
AND r.request_to='Tokyo' AND s.s_before<='user_defined_date'
ORDER BY d.departure_date
```

But it's quite difficult to make suggestions when I don't know the full schema of those table, and what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I've eventually figured out that that is exactly what I need to do and it works well, - simply fetch that user_defined_date solves it all. but still thanks for advise and effort - I'll mark is as an answer.